# PyYaml - overwrite yaml file automatically with inserted argparse parameters

Tags: python, yaml

what I am loading a yaml file and updating it with argparse. what is your feedback on how to update yaml parameters automatically without checking if a argparse parameter is None.
There are almost 20 configuration parameters that with this current version I have to put 20 `if` conditions.

the output of yaml.save_load is:

```
import os
import argparse
import yaml
import functools
import datetime

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    "--config",
    nargs="?",
    type=str,
    default="p.yml",
    help="Configuration file to use",
)
parser.add_argument('--learning_rate', type=float, default=0.001, help='learning rate amount')

args = parser.parse_args()


def yaml_dump(file_path, data):
    """
    Write data into yaml file in file_path
    :param file_path:
    :param data:
    :return: void
    """
    with open(file_path, 'w') as file_descriptor:
        yaml.safe_dump(data, file_descriptor)


def yaml_loader(file_path):
    """
    Load yaml file
    :param file_path:
    :return: yaml file configuration
    """
    with open(file_path, "r") as file_descriptor:
        return yaml.safe_load(file_descriptor)


cfg = yaml_loader(args.config)
if args.learning_rate is not None:
    cfg['training']['optimizer']['lr'] = args.learning_rate


ts = str(datetime.datetime.now()).split(".")[0].replace(" ", "_")
ts = ts.replace(":", "_").replace("-", "_")
logdir = os.path.join("runs", os.path.basename(args.config)[:-4], ts)
yaml_dump(os.path.join(logdir, args.config.split('/')[-1]), cfg)
```

here is the content of `p.yaml` file:

```
model:
    arch: fcn8s
data:
    dataset: pascal
    train_split: train
    val_split: val
    img_rows: 'same'
    img_cols: 'same'
    path: VOC/
    sbd_path: VOC/benchmark_RELEASE/
training:
    train_iters: 300000
    batch_size: 1
    val_interval: 1000
    n_workers: 16
    print_interval: 50
    optimizer:
        name: 'sgd'
        lr: 1.0e-10
        weight_decay: 0.0005
        momentum: 0.99
    loss:
        name: 'cross_entropy'
        size_average: False
    lr_schedule:
    resume: fcn8s_pascal_best_model.pkl
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Code Review is a platform where you can get feedback from other users on *working* code. Questions on how to fix certain errors are better suited for Stack Overflow. See also [How to ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Alex I have updated the code with a working code. now I am asking other users about their feedback on how to make it more efficient. Is it still not suited for StackExchange?

Comment: There's a space before `def yaml_dump` please ensure that this code does run :)

Comment: @Peilonrayz it has been corrected.

Comment: Depending on how the file is used, PyYAML is not really suited for this kind of updating. If the file needs to stay as much the same as possible, e.g. when it is checked into a revision control system, you'll run into spurious changes, like the key order of mappings, loss of superfluous quotes, and if there had been comments those are lost as well. You also have to adhere to YAML 1.1 (replaced in 2009 by YAML 1.2, which PyYAML hasn't been updated to).

Answer (score 1):

While you cannot iterate over a `Namespace` directly, you can parse it into a dictionary using `vars` and iterate over that, if you have a mapping from the argparse name to the path in the config file. The hardest part is using this path to get to the right level in the dictionary:

```
from argparse import Namespace

# Hard-code command line arguments instead of parsing them
args = Namespace(learning_rate=0.001)
# fake having read the config file
cfg = {"training": {"optimizer": {"lr": 0}}}
# mapping from argparse name to path in config file
cfg_path = {"learning_rate": ('training', 'optimizer', 'lr')}

for name, value in vars(args).items():
    if value is None:
        continue
    # go down to right level
    d = cfg
    keys = cfg_path[name]
    for key in keys[:-1]:
        d = d[key]
    # assign value, using the fact that dictionaries are mutable
    d[keys[-1]] = value
```

This will override values where you have a default value in argparse that is not `None`, which may for example change the order in which elements appear in your dictionaries.